# How to call a function only when a user updates fields, not when they are updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my view form.html

```
Size <select ng-model="size" ng-options...>[1..20]</select>
Limiter <select ng-model="limiter">[1..20]</select>
```

and then in the controller  form.js   I have

```
$scope.$watch("limiter", function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    size=Math.min(limiter,size);
  }
});
```

This is all working fine, and now I want to add a sizeMemory, so if the limiter shrinks the size, but is then raised again, then the size will go back up.

This is what I tried, but when the limiter changes the size, the size watcher also changes the sizeMemory.  I need to change this size watch function so it only runs when the user manually sets a value for size:

```
sizeMemory = size;
$scope.$watch("size", function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    sizeMemory=size;
  }
});
$scope.$watch("limiter", function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    wantedSize = Math.max(size,sizeMemory);
    size=Math.min(limiter,wantedSize);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have to use $watch ?

Comment: no, that is just what I know.  I think watch is the correct thing for limiter, but not for size.  Any alternatives more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all you need is [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), it won't be fired when model is changed programatically.

Comment: thank you.  I'd looked at that, but the link you gave me was the perfect example.